# What is the default value of unsigned variable?

Tags: c++

I have a program in C++. I did something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
unsigned x,cifra,cifraOld;
std::cout<<cifra;
}
```

For some reason, the output was `8`. Can someone tell me if `8` is the default value for unsigned variable? If not, why is this happening to me?

Changing the line to `unsigned x,cifra=0,cifraOld;` will output `0`.

Comment: There is no default value. Accessing an uninitialized variable is *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 4):

This declaration:

```
unsigned cifra;
```

initializes `cifra` to an *indeterminate* value.

Reading from an indeterminate value, e.g. like this:

```
std::cout<<cifra;
```

invokes undefined behavior (UB).

Printing 8 is entirely possible for a program with UB. It could print 0, or 42, or "hello world" for that matter. And in fact, the program could print not just *any value*, but as far as the language is concerned, *anything* could happen. In practice, you'll usually get some numeric value (which is a value that just happened to be at the memory location that was read from). If you're lucky the program will segfault, and alert you to the UB before it causes a serious issue.

Comment: @ezluci *undefined behavior* means you can get any value

Comment: In practice, you usually seem to get whatever garbage value happens to be lying around on the stack.